# C# Adding a root to an XDocument

Tags: c#, xml, xml-parsing, linq-to-xml

I have a string that contains an XML, lets say like this:

```
<Novels> 
 <Book>
  <Title>Cat in hat</Title>
  <Price>12</Price>
 </Book>
</Novels>
```

I want to make an XDocument that looks like this:

```
<Booklist>
 <Novels> 
  <Book>
   <Title>Cat in hat</Title>
   <Price>12</Price>
  </Book>
 </Novels>
</Booklist>
```

I can load the xml string into an XDocument using `XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(xmlString);`

How would I load the document under a new root. I can think of something like creating a new XDocument with the root I want and then using a for loop to add the nodes as children, but is there an easier way of doing this?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
XDocument yourResult = new XDocument(new XElement("Booklist", doc.Root));
```

Answer (score 8):

```
var doc = new XDocument(new XElement("Booklist", source.Root));
```

It does not require any parsing at all. There is a deep copy of XElement made, so there is also no references between old and new documents.